# LAN has two entry points - how to manage traffic

Tags: networking, cisco-asa, udp

I asked [this question yesterday](https://serverfault.com/questions/511084/nat-routing-and-port-forwarding-on-cisco-asa-5505) when I (seemingly) couldn't get traffic across my router.

I've spent a lot of time since then with packet capturing, the ASA 5505 cli/ASDM and wireshark.

I've finally realised that my issue is that there are two entries to the LAN.

The LAN is 10.10.5.0/24, with a PDC (DHCP/DNS/etc) at 10.10.5.5, Watchguard Firewall at 10.10.5.1

One entry point has a Watchguard Firewall set up and it's purpose is to manage almost all of the traffic in our organisation. In fact, it does all the traffic except for one specific set.

Which is the other entry point, for a single client. That client's server is at 10.10.5.30 and the ASA 5505 router is 10.10.5.2 (bridged across a modem).

We run services on a number of our servers, on UDP 3000. For all the other servers, all internet, ftp and etc traffic we want it to go out the main Watchguard gateway. And it does.

But for that one server, I want just the port 3000-3002 UDP to go out through the ASA 5505. All UDP data from other servers (including port 3000-3002) is to go through the WG.

I've discovered that while the traffic is coming in through 10.10.5.2 (the ASA5505), the correct server, 10.10.5.30, is receiving the data, BUT then 10.10.5.30 is trying to send the ACK requests back across the 10.10.5.1 firewall.

The symptoms are that it looks like the ASA has no traffic going across it, and we aren't getting any flow. How can I force certain protocols and ports for this server across the ASA rather than the WG?

The ASA 5505 has NAT rules to forward all UDP straight to .30 and to drop everything else.

Important Notes: **other** servers are using the same protocol and port through the WatchGuard at 10.10.5.1, so I can't just push ALL the LAN's UDP port 3000 data out the one connection - I need to split it.

**Update**
Essentially I need to create a route on the server 10.10.5.30 explicitly for UDP ports 3000-3002. I think. It is a Windows 2003 Server SP2

Answer (score 1):

Gah.

route -p add 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.10.5.2 metric 2

Gives me a persistent new gateway across the desired ASA 5505.

The metric of 2 means that the server's current gateway still exists but is deprecated (metric 10) and this is reflected in ipconfig - 10.10.5.2 is now the default gateway.

Comment: Note that your new route will be used for *any* traffic, not just the UDP traffic you were aiming for. If you need policy routing (routing based on other characteristics than the destination IP address), Windows would not let you do this, so you would need another routing device capable of policy routing and taking all the traffic from 10.10.5.30

Comment: Yes, thanks for making that point @syneticon-dj - I discovered that adding the route was sufficient for getting the system back to a working state, and given the time already invested I decided to leave it at that. I was wondering if it were possible in Windows. While it's disappointing that it isn't, I can understand why it isn't (leave the routing to the routers, do what you do best)